# How can I convert an array to JSON?

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, collections

I have an array that I need to convert to a JSON file. There is a text file that holds the data. But I don't understand why it only adds one record.

```py
import collections
list = []
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        info = line.split()
        lists = ("ip" + " " + info[0].replace(":", " ").split()[0] + " " + "port" + " " + info[0].replace(":", " ").split()[1] + " " + "region" + " " + info[1].replace("-", " ").split()[0]).split()
        list.append(lists)
        d = collections.defaultdict(dict)
        for l in list:
            d[l[0]] = l[1]
            d[l[2]] = l[3]
            d[l[4]] = l[5]
print(json.dumps(d))
with open("proxy.json", "w") as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(d))
```

Example of a text file:

```
154.0.5.178:8080 ZA-N-S! - 
119.28.156.115:3128 KR-N - 
207.144.111.230:8080 US-H - 
3.20.236.208:49205 US-H-S - 
217.60.194.43:8080 IR-N! - 
190.61.41.106:999 CO-N-S +
```

What I get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOqHa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
info[1].replace("-", " ").split()[0]
```

will always return a single value! Try this:

```
import json

alist = []
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        info = line.split()
        data = {"ip": info[0].split(":")[0], "port": info[0].split(":")[1],"region": info[1].split("-")}
        alist.append(data)
print(json.dumps(alist))
with open("proxy.json", "w") as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(alist))
```